# What's the c# equivalent of New-SPClaimsPrincipal in powershell

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, claims, trusted-identity-provider

I am using following powershell command to get AD group claim from FQDN of AD grp

```
$ADclaim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "trustedIdentifierName" -ClaimValue "cn=adGrpame,ou=xxx,ou=groups,dc=yyy,dc=zzz" -ClaimType 

"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
```

Executing $ADclaim.ToEncodedString() returns me claim in the following format

```
c:0-.t|trustedIdentifierName|cn=adGrpame%2cou=xxx%2cou=groups%2cdc=yyy%2cdc=zzz
```

I want to achieve the same in c#, Unnecessarily I dont want to invoke powershell from c#.

I have tried following approaches

```
SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(SPClaimTypes.TokenReference, "cn=" + groupname + ",ou=xxx,ou=groups,dc=yyy,dc=zzz", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.ClaimProvider, "trustedIdentifierName"));
```

Not working claim.ToEncodedString() returns empty string

Tried this also

```
SPClaimProviderManager cpm = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
SPClaim userClaim = cpm.ConvertIdentifierToClaim("cn=" + groupname + ",ou=xxx,ou=groups,dc=yyy,dc=zzz", SPIdentifierTypes.FormsRole);
```

not working, If tried the above with SPIdentifierTypes.WindowsSecurityGroupSid then it returns the wrong claim

```
c:0+.w|cn=adGrpame%2cou=xxx%2cou=groups%2cdc=yyy%2cdc=zzz
```